# Obtener nombre de la propiedad y valor de una Lista de Objectos C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase con las siguientes propiedades:

```
public class Datos
    {       
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Peso { get; set; }
    }
```

Como es un `JSON` lo deserializo y usando esa clase:

```
var modelo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datos>>(jsonRecibido);
```

Yo para acceder a los datos de este nuevo objecto lo pasaba a un foreach y sacaba los datos por el nombre de la propiedad asi:

```
foreach (var item in modelo)
            {

                var id = item.ID;
                var nombre = item.Nombre;
                var peso = item.Peso;
}
```

Aqui viene mi duda, como puedo hacer ese mismo foreach pero yo no sabiendo ni el nombre de la propiedad ni el valor por ejemplo algo asi:

```
var ListaNombre=new List<string>();
var ListaValor=new List<string>();
foreach(var item in modelo)
{
      ListaNombre.Add(item...Name/Propiedad); //se guarda el nombre ya sea ID, Nombre, Peso, etc
      ListaValor.Add(item...Value);  //aqui iria "pepe", 4, 67567, etc
}
```

Como haria eso?

Comment: probaste con reflection?

Comment: suena muy fuerte a un tema de reflection

Comment: @gbianchi no se como se haria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como comenta @gbianchi, es un tema que se resuelve usando [Reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), concretamente te voy a dar una solución usando [`GetProperties`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-5.0) y [`GetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0):

```
foreach (var item in modelo)
{
    PropertyInfo[] propiedades = item.GetType().GetProperties(); //obtenemos la colección PropertyInfo con todas las propiedades del objeto
    foreach (var propiedad in propiedades)
    {
        ListaNombre.Add(propiedad.Name); //añadimos el nombre
        ListaValor.Add(propiedad.GetValue(item, null).ToString()); Obtenemos el valor con GetValue
    }

}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que los valores los estamos almacenando como `string`. Se podría asignar al tipo concreto, pero eso sería un tema mas complejo.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias